# Erro ao fazer GET em .net CORE

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Boa tarde, estou estudando .net core com Angular e ao fazer uma requisição GET tenho o seguinte erro:

> : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
>         An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternException: In a
>   route parameter, '{' and '}' must be escaped with '{{' and '}}'.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ProAgil.Domain;
using ProAgil.Repository;

namespace ProAgil.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EventoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IProAgilRepository _repo;
        public EventoController(IProAgilRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            try
            {
                var results = await _repo.GetAllEventoAsync(true);
                return Ok(results);
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Banco de Dados Falhou");
            }

        }

        [HttpGet("{EventoId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int EventoId)
        {
            try
            {
                var results = await _repo.GetAllEventoAsyncById(EventoId, true);
                return Ok(results);
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Banco de Dados Falhou");
            }

        }

        [HttpGet("getByTema/{tema}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string tema)
        {
            try
            {
                var results = await _repo.GetAllEventoAsyncByTema(tema, true);
                return Ok(results);
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Banco de Dados Falhou");
            }

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Evento model)
        {
            try
            {
                _repo.Add(model);

                if(await _repo.SaveChangesAsync())
                {
                    return Created($"/api/evento/{model.Id}", model);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Banco de Dados Falhou");
            }
            return BadRequest();

        }

        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Put(int EventoId, Evento model)
        {
            try
            {

                var evento = await _repo.GetAllEventoAsyncById(EventoId, false);

                if(evento == null) return NotFound();

                _repo.Update(model);

                if(await _repo.SaveChangesAsync())
                {
                    return Created($"/api/evento/{model.Id}", model);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Banco de Dados Falhou");
            }
            return BadRequest();

        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int EventoId)
        {
            try
            {

                var evento = await _repo.GetAllEventoAsyncById(EventoId, false);

                if(evento == null) return NotFound();

                _repo.Delete(evento);

                if(await _repo.SaveChangesAsync())
                {
                    return Ok();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Banco de Dados Falhou");
            }
            return BadRequest();

        }
    }
}
```

e no postman faço a requisição: http://localhost:5000/api/evento/1

Acredito que isso é algum problema com .net core e rota, mas não sei onde resolver.
grato.

Comment: Posta também o código do seu request no angular e do controller no .net.

Comment: esse comecinho aqui [Route("api/[controller]")] ,  o controller está entre colchetes, tá certo isso? não seriam chaves?

Comment: Lucas, obrigado pela resposta, a rota no .net é assim mesmo, está igual a documentação [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Pode postar o startup?